# Cleveref does not capitalize German theorem names

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, amsthm

When using `cleveref` in combination with German theorem names from `amsthm`, referenced theorem names are not capitalized (but they should be).

Referenced chapter names are capitalized as expected.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Satz}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter / Erstes Kapitel} \label{c}

\begin{thm} \label{t}
    Important theorem.
\end{thm}

From \cref{t} in \cref{c} we can deduce that \LaTeX{} is great.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\Cref{t}` helps. Or use the `capitalise` option

Comment: German is a unique language in that it keeps the uppercase initial for nouns. For other languages it can be a stylistic decision: in English it's common to see “in Theorem 1.2”, which would be not so good in Italian, where “nel teorema 1.2” should be preferred. For German as the main language, the `capitalise` option seems the best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use the `capitalise` option which makes recommended for the German language or on a local base use `\Cref{t}` if used in a document with multiple languages, where capitalized names would look awkward in languages other than German.

If `capitalise` is not used, `cleveref` automatically applies `\MakeLowercase` for the given `theorem` etc. name, so `Satz` becomes `satz` in `\cref`.

`\cref{c}` shows up with `Kapitel` just because `\crefname{chapter}` is defined with `Kapitel` already in `cleveref.sty` when `ngerman` is recognized as language setting -- this predefinition is of course not possible for new entities (with rather uncommon names)

I don't recommend such short label names such as `t` or `c`, however.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Satz}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter / Erstes Kapitel} \label{c}

\begin{thm} \label{t}
    Important theorem.
\end{thm}

From \cref{t} in \cref{c} we can deduce that \LaTeX{} is great.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think the `capitalise` option is the way to go there. Longer label names are definitely better, I only used short ones for the MWE.

Comment: @jpmath: Yes, but you should not use it in multi-language documents